# Laravel Exists rule on mutliple columns with OR combiner

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have a rule that do something like following:

```sql
... from users where email = 'IDENTIFIER' or mobile = 'IDENTIFIER'
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AuthIdentifyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'identifier' => [
                'exists:users,email[OR]mobile'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this situation in Laravel?

I'm using Laravel 8.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the answer you are hoping for, but it should achieve the desired result.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'identifier' => [
            // use the @ symbol to differentiate email and mobile inputs
            Str::contains($this->identifier,'@')
                ? 'exists:users,email'
                : 'exists:users,mobile'
        ],
    ];
}
```